# Can't change innerHTML when using Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the  but at the moment it currently isn't changing text when I check other radio buttons.

I've tried changing the values in my HTML inputs, and searched through the mozilla JS helpers but can't seem to find a fix.

```js
let shapeChoice = document.querySelector('input[name="shape"]:checked').value;

switch (shapeChoice) {
  case 'circV':
    document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = "Circle Area"
    break;

  case 'rectV':
    document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = "Rectangle Area"
    break;

  case 'triV':
    document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = "Triangle Area"
    break;

  case 'paraV':
    document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = "Parallelogram Area"
    break;

  default:
    doucment.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = "Default"
}
```

```html
<div id="radioHeader">
  <input type="radio" name="shape" value="circV" onclick="" checked>
  <label for="circleID">Circle</label>

  <input type="radio" name="shape" value="rectV">
  <label for="rectangleID">Rectangle</label>

  <input type="radio" name="shape" value="triV">
  <label for="triangleID">Triangle</label>

  <input type="radio" name="shape" value="paraV">
  <label for="parallelogramID">Parallelogram</label> <br>

  <p id="debug1"></p>
</div>
```

on load "Circle Area" should be displayed underneath the radio boxes, but upon checking the other radios, it change to the corresponding shape's + Area.

However, I'm only getting "Circle Area" even if I check another radio box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should attach an `onclick` event. when event occur then check all cases. as i bellow described.

```js
function radioClicked(){
  let shapeChoice = document.querySelector('input[name="shape"]:checked').value;

switch (shapeChoice) {
  case 'circV':
    document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = "Circle Area"
    break;

  case 'rectV':
    document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = "Rectangle Area"
    break;

  case 'triV':
    document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = "Triangle Area"
    break;

  case 'paraV':
    document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = "Parallelogram Area"
    break;

  default:
    doucment.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = "Default"
}
};

radioClicked();
```

```html
<div id="radioHeader" onload="radioClicked()" onclick="radioClicked()" >
    <input type="radio" name="shape" value="circV" onclick="" checked>
    <label for="circleID">Circle</label>
  
    <input type="radio" name="shape" value="rectV">
    <label for="rectangleID">Rectangle</label>
  
    <input type="radio" name="shape" value="triV">
    <label for="triangleID">Triangle</label>
  
    <input type="radio" name="shape" value="paraV">
    <label for="parallelogramID">Parallelogram</label> <br>
  
    <p id="debug1"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I would also add if you want the text to be displayed for your circle radio button when your web page loads then you will need to call the function in your javascript so that the function is also executed when the javascript is initially loaded into your webpage.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, this has fixed my issue so I can now get to actual functionality!